# Is it correct to separate a limit, apply Stirling and then reattach it?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I don't know if I can do this with my limit:

> $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {n \left( 2\,n \right) ^{2\,n}{
> {\rm e}^{-2\,n}}}{ \left( 2\,n \right) !} \left( {\frac { \left( 2\,n
>  \right) !}{ \left( 2\,n \right) ^{2\,n}{{\rm e}^{-2\,n}}}}-{\frac {
>  \left( 2\,n+2 \right) !}{ \left( 2\,n+2 \right) ^{2\,n+2}{{\rm e}^{-2
> \,n-2}}}} \right) }=
> $$
>
> $$=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {n}{ \sqrt{4\,\pi \,n}} \left( {
> \frac { \left( 2\,n \right) !}{ \left( 2\,n \right) ^{2\,n}{{\rm e}^{-
> 2\,n}}}}-{\frac { \left( 2\,n+2 \right) !}{ \left( 2\,n+2 \right) ^{2
> \,n+2}{{\rm e}^{-2\,n-2}}}} \right) }=
> $$
>
> $$=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {n \left( 2\,n \right) !}{ \left( 2
> \,n \right) ^{2\,n}{{\rm e}^{-2\,n}} \sqrt{4\,\pi \,n}}}-\lim _{n
> \rightarrow \infty }{\frac {n \left( 2\,n+2 \right) !}{ \left( 2\,n+2
>  \right) ^{2\,n+2}{{\rm e}^{-2\,n-2}} \sqrt{4\,\pi \,n}}}=
> $$
>
> $$=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {n \sqrt{4\,\pi \,n}-n \sqrt{2\,
> \pi \, \left( 2\,n+2 \right) }}{ \sqrt{4\,\pi \,n}}}=
> \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac {\sqrt{2\,{n}^{2}}- \sqrt{2\,{n}^{
> 2}+2\,n}}{ \sqrt{2}}.
> $$

Is "legal" to separate the limit, apply Stirling and then reattach it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- You can separate the limit into two terms or factors if both of them converge.
- You don't need to separate them to apply Stirling's formula.
- You don't even need to apply Stirling's approximation at all, since the factorials in the numerators and denominator cancel each other almost completely out.